# Gradle.properties: Is it possible to save not string values?

Tags: gradle

Here example of my gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M
org.gradle.caching=true
RELEASE_STORE_FILE="MyProject/build/someFile"
```

OK. It's work.
But I want to store no string value. Something like this:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M
org.gradle.caching=true
RELEASE_STORE_FILE=project.rootDir + File.separatorChar + "build" + File.separatorChar + "someFile"
```

But value of **RELEASE_STORE_FILE** is string:

```
project.rootDir + File.separatorChar + " build" + File.separatorChar + "someFile"
```

How I can save not string value?

Comment: You can't. A properties file has a very simple syntax, a string key and a string value.

Comment: Why not just compute is in the build script?

Comment: **RELEASE_STORE_FILE** contain secure/confidential data. I don't want to do this in _build.gradle_

Comment: So read it directly in the application from e.g. a plain file or system variable.